# I twisted a L200CV in Pentawatt package; what kind of damage can I expect?

Tags: mechanical-assembly

I was installing a heatsink which didn't quite fit and after installing it, I noticed that I've twisted the L200CV about 5° when looking from above the chip. What kind of damage, if any, can I expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you bent the leads after the package was soldered in, the solder joints may have cracked. It is worth touching them up. Ensure you don't dry them out by using flux and a reasonable temperature.

The regulator itself will be fine. Leads are meant to be bent.

Comment: I twisted the leads and solder after that, so soldering is fine. Also, my continuity test says so.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, Note that continuity test will often pass despite cracked or 'lifted' (poor trace contact) solder joints, and leads to horrible pseudo-random types of faults. Won't happen in this case, since you soldered after bending, but good to know!

Comment: It is also possible to crack the case by bending leads (tubes, ceramic caps especially) but I think the L200 and other IC's can take considerable abuse without damage.

Comment: I finally managed to get the circuit working, and the chip seems undamaged.